Extract Combination of values from 1 table not in another table
2 tables with similar information. There are n number of Unique Teams and 2 unique Types and 2 Unique Products. So, for each Team there are 4 rows in Table 1.
Table 1



Team
Type
Product




Team1
New
TV


Team1
New
Laptop


Team1
Repeat
TV


Team1
Repeat
Laptop


Team2
Repeat
TV


Team2
New
TV


Team2
New
Laptop


Team2
Repeat
Laptop


Team3
New
Laptop



Table 2 - Does not have some Teams; If it has matching Teams, it does not have matching Type; If Teams and Type match, it may not match the Product.



Team
Type
Product




Team1
New
TV


Team1
New
Laptop


Team1
Repeat
TV


Team2
Repeat
TV



Desired Output Table = Rows that are not in Table 2



Team
Type
Product




Team1
Repeat
Laptop


Team2
New
TV


Team2
New
Laptop


Team2
Repeat
Laptop


Team3
New
Laptop



SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE NOT EXISTS SELECT * FROM table2 did not work. Returned no output.

A quick look for a tutorial on how to correctly use not exists will solve this for you.

Sure, you could make NOT EXISTS work in this case but since you're checking for the existence of matching data across all columns, why not EXCEPT?

Assuming you ran that query with brackets around the sub-query after NOT EXISTS (most systems wouldn't accept that syntax without parenthesis), 'Returned no output' because there is no qualification on table2. For each row in table1 it checks to see if table2 has any rows. there exist 5 rows in Table2, every time (no criteria present), so NOT EXISTS fails.

First method using LEFT JOIN :
SELECT t1.* FROM table1 t1
 LEFT JOIN table2 t2
 ON t1.team = t2.team and t1.type = t2.type and t1.product = t2.product
 WHERE t2.team IS NULL;

Second method using NOT EXISTS :
select * from table1 t1 where not exists
(select * from table2 t2 
where t1.team = t2.team and t1.type = t2.type and t1.product = t2.product) 

